# Customise InteliSense information

Tags: c#, intellisense

is there a way to customize IntelliSense information?

I know i can use XML-Comments to show detail information's.
When i use the Obsolete Attribute, there is the hint [deprecated] in the IntelliSense.

I created Attributes for Properties. With these Attribute i can control Translations for some Dialog areas. Now i want to show these information's also in my IntelliSense.
There must be a way to customize this part of IntelliSense.

I have searched for this but get only results how to manipulate the autocomplete of IntelliSense.

How can i do this?

Comment: You will need to write your own visual studio extention. There is no simple customization other than the options in the editor menu. Just look at [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/obsoleteattribute.cs): there's nothing special there, so the magic is happening _in_ the compiler and intellisense.

Comment: So... i think a QuickInfoSource is my solution. Anybody knows how to get the instance of the hovered object?